# Google map does not load when application published on IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using google map / api in my application.

Application running fine on my local machine, but when i published it to the IIS then google map does not load.

please reply if anyone has idea.

Thanks

Comment: what version of Google API? what is the code you're using?

Comment: we are not using any specific version but directly acccessing https://www.google.com/jsapi and our application is in asp.net mvc 4

Answer (score -3):

get an api key for your server. You must set your server Ip to google.
Here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
Use **Create New Server Key**

Comment: this would make maps work with a warning, not stop them from working alltogether.

Comment: No. I am using now. I set my server Ip there is no problem for 1 week. And thne you must get an api key paying money to google.

Comment: That depends on usage -- if you are below the limit for free tier you don't have to pay. See [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage_limits)